# How to find the correct custom format for a date-time string

Tags: c#, winforms, datetime

I read date-time strings from a file in **2** different formats:

1. `19/02/2019 08:24:59`
2. `2/17/2019 12:25:46 PM`

For the *first* format the custom format string I wrote is:

```
string firstDate = "19/02/2019 08:24:59";
string customFormatForFirstDateTimeString = "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss";
```

and I use it as follows:

```
string firstResultingDateAndTime;

bool parsingSuccessful = DateTime.TryParseExact(
  firstDate, 
  customFormatForFirstDateTimeString, 
  System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
  System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, 
  out firstResultingDateAndTime);
```

The problem is that `parsingSuccessful` results `false`.
For the *second* date-time string, the code is as follows:

```
string secondDate = "2/17/2019 12:25:46 PM";
string customFormatForSecondDateTimeString = "m/dd/yyy hh:mm:ss PM";
string secondResultingDateAndTime;

parsingSuccessful = DateTime.TryParseExact(
  secondDate, 
  customFormatForSecondDateTimeString, 
  System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
  System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, 
  out secondResultingDateAndTime);
```

Also here I receive

```
parsingSuccessful == false;
```

I reckon that the custom format strings do not fit the date-time strings, but I was not able to *figure out why*.
Please help.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: `mm` stands for **minutes** in `"dd/mm/yyyy...` put `MM` - months - instead; ` "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss";` (`HH` hour in `0..23` range). `"M/dd/yyy hh:mm:ss tt"`;

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, `mm` stands for **minutes**, not **months** (we have `MM` for it) that's why `dd/mm/yyyy` format should be `dd/MM/yyyy`.
Another issue with **hour** format where we have `hh` for `0..12` range (with `tt` for `AM/PM`) and `HH` for `0..23` interval:

```
 string firstDate = "19/02/2019 08:24:59";
 // Since we don't have AM / PM we can conclude that hour is in 0..23 range 
 string customFormatForFirstDateTimeString = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss";

 string secondDate = "2/17/2019 12:25:46 PM";
 string customFormatForSecondDateTimeString = "M/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt";
```

Comment: Why the capital HH, is there any reason for that?? Is that because of 12 hr format

Comment: @Anil: Capital `HH` stands for hour in `00..23` range (*24h format*) when `hh` is for *12h format*. First format doesn't include AM/PM, that's why we can assume that 24h format used (otherwise we have an ambiguity: `8` can mean either `8 AM` or `8 PM`)

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Thanks :)